# c++ multiple defined in .obj

Tags: c++, mfc, header-files

So I have 3 MFC dialogs:

1. Dialog1 - main dialog
2. Dialog2 - sub dialog of Dialog1
3. Dialog3 - sub dialog of Dialog2

XXXResourceFile.h - resource file used by Dialog2 and Dialog3; contains only resources (macro constants, typedef structs which is used only in the file, and arrays of the typedefed struct); no class

In Dialog1, I need reference of Dialog2 (for showing window/modal).

In Dialog2, I need reference of both Dialog1 ( for calling GetParent() ), and 3 (for showing window/modal)

In Dialog3, I need reference of both Dialog1 and 2 ( for calling GetParent()/ GetAncestor() )

**Current design:**

```
//Dialog1.h - by co-dev
...
#include Dialog2.h"
...

//Dialog2.cpp - by co-dev
...
#include "Dialog2.h"
#include "XXXResourceFile.h"
#include "Dialog1.h"
#include "Dialog3.h"
...

//Dialog3.cpp - my initial code/design
...
#include "Dialog3.h"
#include "Dialog2.h"
#include "Dialog1.h"
#include "XXXResourceFile.h"
```

**My ideal design:**

```
//Dialog1.h
#include "Dialog2.h"
...

//Dialog2.h
#include "Dialog1.h"
#include "Dialog3.h"
#include "XXXResourceFile.h"

//Dialog3.h
#include "Dialog1.h"
```

Now on the current design, I added `#pragma once` in all of these headers. I am getting error lnk 2005 (says that arrays from the XXXResourceFile is already defined in Dialog3.obj, can't double click on error since it's not on the headers nor source files but on the obj).

My questions are:

1. Can you comment on the current design and the ideal design of this files? What needs correction, what is missing, etc...
2. I don't think I've fully understood usage of `#pragma once`. In my knowledge (also based on what my co-devs say), it is included only in header files. What about cpp files?
3. Also since my problem is the inclusion of XXXResourceFile.h, is the correct usage of `#pragma once` supposed to be on **this header**? Or the **files that will include this header**? This bit is the part where I'm really confused.

Comment: The code posted does not result in **any** object code being generated. It is insufficient to illustrate your problem.

Answer (score -1):

You have header circular dependency here:

```
//Dialog1.h
#include "Dialog2.h"
...

//Dialog2.h
#include "Dialog1.h"
#include "Dialog3.h"
#include "XXXResourceFile.h"

//Dialog3.h
#include "Dialog1.h"
```

Dialog1.h includes Dialog2.h that includes Dialog1.h.

Dialog1.h includes Dialog2.h that includes Dialog3.h that includes Dialog1.h.

You can break this using forward declarations and pointer types.

```
// Dialog1.h 
class Dialog2;

class Dialog1
{
  Dialog2* ptrDialog2;
};

// Dialog1.cpp
#include "Dialog2.h"

// Dialog2.h 
class Dialog1;

class Dialog2
{
  Dialog1* ptrDialog1;
};

// Dialog2.cpp
#include "Dialog1.h"
```

Comment: This is a solution to a different problem.